# I can't show the icon of my application in iTunes

Tags: ios, itunes

I make an iPhone application and my customer want to see that. So I created a ipa file, but there is no icon :

[image]

I don't understand because on the iPhone there is no problem :

[image]

Would I forget a picture format?

[image]

For info, this application is not on the App Store now. It's only for the customer and for my boss (they need to check).

Thank You!

--- Edit:

Thank you for your many reply but after message of @Vakas I add iTunesArtwork and iTunesArtwork@2x, two png files without extension like this (but no effect):

config.xml:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget android-versionCode="15" id="com.ionicframework.test5119111" ios-CFBundleVersion="8.4" version="0.0.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
    <preference name="AllowInlineMediaPlayback" value="false" />
    <preference name="BackupWebStorage" value="cloud" />
    <preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="false" />
    <preference name="EnableViewportScale" value="false" />
    <preference name="KeyboardDisplayRequiresUserAction" value="true" />
    <preference name="MediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction" value="false" />
    <preference name="SuppressesIncrementalRendering" value="false" />
    <preference name="GapBetweenPages" value="0" />
    <preference name="PageLength" value="0" />
    <preference name="PaginationBreakingMode" value="page" />
    <preference name="PaginationMode" value="unpaginated" />
    <feature name="LocalStorage">
        <param name="ios-package" value="CDVLocalStorage" />
    </feature>
    <feature name="Keyboard">
        <param name="ios-package" onload="true" value="IonicKeyboard" />
    </feature>
    <feature name="Console">
        <param name="ios-package" value="CDVLogger" />
    </feature>
    <feature name="Device">
        <param name="ios-package" value="CDVDevice" />
    </feature>
    <preference name="AndroidPersistentFileLocation" value="Internal" />
    <feature name="File">
        <param name="ios-package" value="CDVFile" />
        <param name="onload" value="true" />
    </feature>
    <feature name="FileTransfer">
        <param name="ios-package" value="CDVFileTransfer" />
    </feature>
    <feature name="SplashScreen">
        <param name="ios-package" value="CDVSplashScreen" />
        <param name="onload" value="true" />
    </feature>
    <icon height="57" src="resources/ios/icon/icon.png" width="57" />
    <icon height="114" src="resources/ios/icon/icon@2x.png" width="114" />
    <icon height="40" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-40.png" width="40" />
    <icon height="80" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-40@2x.png" width="80" />
    <icon height="50" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-50.png" width="50" />
    <icon height="100" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-50@2x.png" width="100" />
    <icon height="60" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-60.png" width="60" />
    <icon height="120" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-60@2x.png" width="120" />
    <icon height="180" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-60@3x.png" width="180" />
    <icon height="72" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-72.png" width="72" />
    <icon height="144" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-72@2x.png" width="144" />
    <icon height="76" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-76.png" width="76" />
    <icon height="152" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-76@2x.png" width="152" />
    <icon height="29" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-small.png" width="29" />
    <icon height="58" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-small@2x.png" width="58" />
    <icon height="87" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-small@3x.png" width="87" />
    <icon height="512" src="resources/ios/icon/iTunesArtwork" width="512" />
    <icon height="1024" src="resources/ios/icon/iTunesArtwork@2x" width="1024" />
    <splash height="1136" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-568h@2x~iphone.png" width="640" />
    <splash height="1334" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-667h.png" width="750" />
    <splash height="2208" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-736h.png" width="1242" />
    <splash height="1242" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Landscape-736h.png" width="2208" />
    <splash height="1536" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Landscape@2x~ipad.png" width="2048" />
    <splash height="768" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Landscape~ipad.png" width="1024" />
    <splash height="2048" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Portrait@2x~ipad.png" width="1536" />
    <splash height="1024" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Portrait~ipad.png" width="768" />
    <splash height="960" src="resources/ios/splash/Default@2x~iphone.png" width="640" />
    <splash height="480" src="resources/ios/splash/Default~iphone.png" width="320" />
    <name>test5</name>
    <description>
        An Ionic Framework and Cordova project.
    </description>
    <author email="hi@ionicframework" href="http://ionicframework.com/">
      Ionic Framework Team
    </author>
    <content src="index.html" />
    <access origin="*" />
    <preference name="orientation" value="portrait" />
    <preference name="HideKeyboardFormAccessoryBar" value="true" />
    <preference name="AndroidPersistentFileLocation" value="Compatibility" />
    <preference name="iosPersistentFileLocation" value="Library" />
    <preference name="iosPersistentFileLocation" value="Compatibility" />
    <preference name="AllowInlineMediaPlayback" value="true" />
    <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="14" />
    <preference name="webviewbounce" value="false" />
    <preference name="UIWebViewBounce" value="false" />
    <preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true" />
    <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="16" />
    <preference name="BackupWebStorage" value="none" />
    <preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen" />
    <preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="3000" />
</widget>
```

folder:

[image]

Maybe it's the same thing like this topic : http://muaca.blogspot.jp/2015/10/cordova-development-ios-itunesartwork.html

But there is not the "devise" folder like them example :

/mobile_app_root/platforms/ios/build/**device/generated-app.app**

This is my folder:

[image]

Comment: Hi, did you solve your problem? In which folder you put iTunesArtwork and iTunesArtwork@2x before build application? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @seikida did you ever solve this?

Answer (score 1):

You’re missing an icon for AppStore with a resolution of 1024 x 1024. Please add that it will show up in the iTunes.

Comment: Thank you for your reply but : How can I do that ?
I add 2 png files : iTunesArtwork and iTunesArtwork@2x but no effect (I use Apache Cordova)

Comment: Try deleting the exiting app in iTunes and the restart iTunes and add your app again.

Comment: Hi, can you explain in which folder need to add iTunesArtwork and  iTunesArtwork@2x images?

Answer (score 0):

You must add the images with the name:

- "iTunesArtwork" (.png, without extension, 512x512) and
- "iTunesArtwork@2x" (1024x1024) in the project.

Comment: Thank you @kennymuse but I already add images without .png extension (I edited my post, please show it).

Comment: In which folder need to add this images?